# Single build with multiple runtime environments using angular azure AD and MSAL

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, angular11

How can i use environment variables at runtime for multiple environments. In app.module.ts i am using environment.clientId it works only for development. I need to configure it one place and at runtime it has to change based on environments (Dev, Prod, Staging, Test).

In app.module.ts
[image]

In app-config.service.ts

[image]

Comment: You can refer to [Msal for Angular Dynamic configuration](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/481)